# PHP removing Non-ASCII characters excluding EUR and GBP signs

Tags: php, preg-replace

This simple line removes any non printable ASCII characters:

```
preg_replace('/[^\x20-\x7E]/', NULL, $string);
```

Is it possible to keep the € and £ signs ?

Comment: Yes put them inside the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a magic tag for currencies: `\p{Sc}` or `\p{Currency_Symbol}`: any currency sign

And you have to put header `UTF8` and should use `/u` modifier to unicode support.

```
header("Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8");

echo preg_replace('/[^\x20-\x7E\p{Sc}]/u', NULL, $string);
```